# Regex works in validator but not in C# [repeated capturing groups issue]

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-group

I have to parse the below string into three groups, Command, Target, Args.
Both Targets and Args are independently optional.

`/ping@mybot arg1 arg2`

I have created a regex with the valuable help of regexr.com, and I get the correct matches here.

`/(?<Command>[\w]*)+(?:@(?<Target>[\S]*)+)?(?<Args>[\s\S]*)?`

[image]

However when I try and plug this into C#, I do not get any Matches, what could I have messed up here? I am @" escaping the string to avoid escaping issues:

`var match = Regex.Match(cmd, @"/(?<Command>[\w]*)+(?:@(?<Target>[\S]*)+)?(?<Args>[\s\S]*)?");`

Does C# require a different set of characters for it's regex?

[image]

Comment: First of all, do you really need the repeated capturing groups? Try just `/(?<Command>\w+)(?:@(?<Target>\S+))?(?<Args>(?s).*)?`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rvmKfc/1).

Comment: Use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) instead. That includes an option for running against the .NET regex implementation instead of the JS one that regexr.com is using.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Removing the repeating capturing groups `[\s]` seems to have done the trick! Happy to accept this as an answer, and thanks @lee-m for suggesting regex101.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert repeated capturing groups into simple groups:

```
/(?<Command>\w+)(?:@(?<Target>\S+))?(?<Args>(?s).*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rvmKfc/2).

Note I also replaced `[\s\S]` with `.` and added the `(?s)` inline modifier option to make the `.` after that modifier match any chars including line break chars. You may remove `(?s)` if you use `RegexOptions.Singleline` option in your code.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/H8F7JN):

```cs
var pattern = @"/(?<Command>\w+)(?:@(?<Target>\S+))?(?<Args>(?s).*)";
var text = "/ping@mybot arg1 arg2";
var match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Command"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Target"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Args"].Value);
}
```

Output:

```
ping
mybot
 arg1 arg2
```